# SELECT One column from multiple tables MSSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Easy task is giving me a hard time. I want to select one column from different tables and insert it in a results table. Basically, much like a union all:

```
SELECT Email FROM TableA
UNION ALL
Select Email FROM TableB
```

and so on...

However, I want to do this in an automated way. As I said, seems so simple, but I am stumbling over it. My code attempt:

```
USE MyDatabase

IF OBJECT_ID ('TEMPDB..#Selection') IS NOT NULL DROP TableA #Selection;
SELECT Name AS TableA, ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RowNumb
INTO #Selection
FROM Sys.TableAs AS T
WHERE NAME LIKE '%abc%'
ORDER BY 2


IF OBJECT_ID ('TEMPDB..#Result') IS NOT NULL DROP TableA #Result;
CREATE TableA #Result ( Email VARCHAR (200))

DECLARE @Counter INT 
SET @Counter = 1


WHILE @Counter <= ( SELECT MAX (RowNumb) FROM #Selection )

BEGIN

DECLARE @Table VARCHAR (100)
SET @Table = ( SELECT TableA FROM #Selection WHERE RowNumb = @Counter )

-- PRINT @Table SET @Counter = @Counter + 1 END

    INSERT INTO #Result
    SELECT Email
    FROM @Table

    SET @Counter = @Counter + 1
END
```

I am sure someone will find my mistakes quickly. Thanks a lot for any guidance!

Kind regards, M.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would (personally) go for something more like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #Email (email nvarchar(200));

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX);

SET @SQL = N'INSERT INTO #Email (Email)' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
           STUFF((SELECT NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) + 
                         N'UNION ALL' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
                         N'SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(200),email)' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10) +
                         N'FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.[name]) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.[name])
                  FROM sys.schemas s
                       JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
                       JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
                  WHERE c.[name] = N'Email'
                  FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value(N'.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,13,N'') + N';';
PRINT @SQL;
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL;

SELECT *
FROM #Email;

DROP TABLE #Email;
```

This creates a dynamic statement that creates a `UNION ALL` query against every table with the column `Email` (in the current database) and inserts the value into said temporary table. It then returns said values from the temporary table (and then disposes of the table, as I don't actually know what you're going to do with it).

Comment: Trying to test it, thanks a lot so far. Where is the filtering based on table name in this query?

Comment: Ah I see, you took another approach. I must have not explained it well. I need the tables as a result where tablename LIKE '%Something%'.

Comment: @SQL_M - You can add a filter on a table name as well along with column name. like this -   t.Name like  '%Something%'

Comment: @Larnu - Why not use Information_Schema.Columns in your solution?

Comment: Made a small adjustment, works like a charm. Thanks!!

Comment: (Old) Habit more than anything @MarkKram. :)

Comment: @Larnu - I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something. Have a great rest of your day!